# quick way to add checkbox jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to add the check box "no end date" to the end of my date picker widget. I see people using "beforeshow" method under datepicker but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here is what I have.

```
$("#to").datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    },
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(input)
                .datepicker("widget")
                .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            var html = '<div class="noEndDate"><input type="checkbox"><label> No End Date </label></div>';
            buttonPane.append(html);
        }, 10);

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the button panel of datepicker in order to target it using `var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");`:

```
showButtonPanel: true,
```

But as your image suggests it, you don't want the button panel, so use instead:

```
var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget");
```

### DEMO